# I cannot add a checkout button in woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a checkout button in product page using the following in functions.php:

```
function add_content_after_addtocart() {

// get the current post/product ID
$current_product_id = get_the_ID();

// get the product based on the ID
$product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );

// get the "Checkout Page" URL
$checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

// run only on simple products
if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){

    <script>
        jQuery(function($) 
        {

               $(".custom-checkout-btn").on("click", function() 
                {
                   $(this).attr("href", function() 
                    {
                        return this.href + '&quantity=' + $('input.qty').val();
                    });

                });?>
        });
    </script>

    echo '<a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">Checkout</a>';
}
}
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart' );
```

How to call this script inside the php function ??

I tried

```
echo "<script> .... </script>";  but is not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script

```
function add_content_after_addtocart() {

    // get the current post/product ID
    $current_product_id = get_the_ID();

    // get the product based on the ID
    $product = wc_get_product( $current_product_id );

    // get the "Checkout Page" URL
    $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

    // run only on simple products
    if( $product->is_type( 'simple' ) ){ ?>

        <script>
            jQuery(function($) 
            {

                   $(".custom-checkout-btn").on("click", function() 
                    {
                       $(this).attr("href", function() 
                        {
                            return this.href + '&quantity=' + $('input.qty').val();
                        });

                    });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        echo '<a href="'.$checkout_url.'?add-to-cart='.$current_product_id.'" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt custom-checkout-btn">Checkout</a>';
    }
}
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'add_content_after_addtocart' );
```

you forgot to add class  `custom-checkout-btn` in anchor tag.

[image]

Comment: Thank you its working, is it normal that it takes me to cart and not to checkout immediately?

Comment: its take me to checkout page. what is the value `$checkout_url`?

Comment: what is the value `$checkout_url`?

Comment: $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url(); you mean this?

Comment: did you add the checkout page in woocomerce settings?

Comment: check https://bestfamily.gr/shop/%CF%80%CE%B1%CE%B9%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%AC/%CE%B2%CF%81%CE%B5%CF%86%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC/%CE%B1%CF%83%CF%86%CE%AC%CE%BB%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1/%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%85%CF%84%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AD%CF%82-%CE%B3%CF%89%CE%BD%CE%B9%CE%AD%CF%82-4%CF%84%CE%BC%CF%87/ yes there is a checkout it is working